# Making steps in a for loop sequential when using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, loops, sequential-workflow

I'm trying to loop through a list of links on a webpage, clicking on each using selenium, then copying a tinylink from each page before finally returning to the master list page. So far it will access the page, but I'm struggling to get the sequentiality of

click link-> load page-> click 'share'-> click 'copy'

Currently it's accessing the master list page and going straight to clicking 'share' before clicking into the first link. Maybe I'm overthinking this, as I thought sleep(1) would cut the program there until the next step. Please help!

```
#below accesses each link, opens the tinylink, and copies it
powerforms = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-content']/ul")
links = powerforms.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

for link in links:
    link.click()
    sleep(1)

    #clicks 'Share' button to open popout
    share = driver.find_element_by_id("shareContentLink")
    share.click()
    sleep(1)

    #clicks 'Copy' button to copy the tinylink to the clipboard
    copy = driver.find_element_by_id("share-link-copy-button")
    copy.click()
    sleep(1)
    break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sleep, you should use `WebDriverWait`, to be sure the element is present on the page, is loaded and interactive. Sleep doesn't take into consideration your internet speed etc.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
max_wait_time = 10 #seconds

powerforms = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='main-content']/ul")
links = powerforms.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")

for link in links:
    try:
        link = WebDriverWait(driver, max_wait_time).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(link))
        link.click()

        # clicks 'Share' button to open popout
        share = WebDriverWait(driver, max_wait_time).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'shareContentLink')))
        share.click()
        # sleep(1)

        # clicks 'Copy' button to copy the tinylink to the clipboard
        copy = WebDriverWait(driver, max_wait_time).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'share-link-copy-button')))
        copy.click()
        # sleep(1)

    except TimeoutException:
        print("Couldn't load element")
        continue
```